# Multiple admob user ads in one app

Tags: android, admob

I´ve made an android app. My plan is to allow each user to place their own ad in the author generated articles.
Till now, no problem. 
So bit tricky:
User can save the ad id generated by admob in their own profile.
Question 1: Allow admob different user link the ad to my app in admob panel?
Next step: every time the user post an article, i link it to the ad id on users profile.
Every time someone opens that article, i get the admob id from the author and show his ad created in admob.

So terms of use by admob AND adsense dont disallow that kind of procedure but not allow it explicite.

And please note, i'm not sharing revenue's. What the users generate through the ad placement will go directly to him.

Question 2: Is it possible and allowed what im thinking to do? When not, what for an alternative you can suggest?

Thank you!